# SQL Script to enter data from another table and create a column in the source table to link another table

Tags: sql

I have a table which already have data in it.

```
Table -> Address:
AddressID, Address 1, Address 2, email etc...

Table -> Branches:
BranchesID, StoreName, Address 1, Address 2
```

Now i need a script which can copy all of the data from Branches table to Address table and create a column in Branches which has AddressID of the newly copied data so i can refer Branches Addresses using the Address Table.

Please help.

I have tried this much so far.

```
INSERT Address1, Address2, City, ZipCode)
OUTPUT AddressID
INTO Addresses
SELECT Address1, Address2
FROM Baranches;
```

BUT i dont know how to insert newly created records ID from Address Table into Braches table ...

tahnks

Comment: i need to create a column which has AddressID. i need to copy all the data from branches table to address table and need those AddressID

Answer (score 2):

First you need to add `AddressId` field into `Branches`. I don't know what RDBMS do you use so here is an example for MSSQL but it should work for all RDBMS with a few changes:

```
ALTER TABLE BRANCHES ADD AddressID bigint;
```

Then insert addresses from `branches` into `Address` table. I guess `AddressId` is autoincremented PK?. `WHERE` statement in this query allows to avoid address duplications.

```
insert into ADDRESS (Address1, Address2)
select Address1, Address2 
    from BRANCHES 
      where 
       not exists(select AddressID 
                        from ADDRESS 
                        where Address1=BRANCHES.Address1
                              and 
                              Address2=BRANCHES.Address2 )
```

Now we should fill in `AddressID` field in the BRANCHES:

```
update BRANCHES SET AddressId=(select TOP 1 AddressId from Address where 
                                   Address1=BRANCHES.Address1
                                    and 
                                   Address2=BRANCHES.Address2 )
```

Comment: i am gonna try this in sometime and let you know if any changes needed